# Inserting into Collection after Promises in a Meteor Method

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I'm using this [Gumroad-API](https://github.com/SamyPesse/gumroad-api) npm package in order to fetch data from an external service (Gumroad). Unfortunately, it seems to use a `.then()` construct which can get a little unwieldy as you will find out below:

This is my meteor method:

```js
Meteor.methods({
  fetchGumroadData: () => {
    const Gumroad = Meteor.npmRequire('gumroad-api');
    let gumroad = new Gumroad({ token: Meteor.settings.gumroadAccessKey });
    let before = "2099-12-04";
    let after = "2014-12-04";
    let page = 1;
    let sales = [];

    // Recursively defined to continue fetching the next page if it exists
    let doThisAfterResponse = (response) => {

      sales.push(response.sales);

      if (response.next_page_url) {

        page = page + 1;
        gumroad.listSales(after, before, page).then(doThisAfterResponse);

      } else {

        let finalArray = R.unnest(sales);
        console.log('result array length: ' + finalArray.length);
        Meteor.call('insertSales', finalArray);
        console.log('FINISHED');

      }
    }

    gumroad.listSales(after, before, page).then(doThisAfterResponse);  // run
  }
});
```

Since the NPM package exposes the Gumorad API using something like this:

```
gumroad.listSales(after, before, page).then(callback)
```

I decided to do it recursively in order to grab all pages of data.

Let me try to re-cap what is happening here:

1. The journey starts on the last line of the code shown above.
2. The initial page is fetched, and `doThisAfterResponse()` is run for the first time.
3. We first **dump the returned data** into our `sales` array, and then we **check if the response has given us a link to the next page** (as an indication as to whether or not we're on the final page).
4. **If so**, we increment our page count and we make the API call again with the same function to handle the response again.
5. **If not**, this means we're at our final page. Now it's time to format the data using `R.unnest` and finally insert the `finalArray` of data into our database.

But a funny thing happens here. The entire execution halts at the `Meteor.call()` and I don't even get an error output to the server logs.

I even tried switching out the `Meteor.call()` for a simple: `Sales.insert({text: 'testing'})` but the exact same behaviour is observed.

What I really need to do is to fetch the information and then store it into the database on the server. How can I make that happen?

**EDIT:** Please also see this other (much more simplified) SO question I made:

[Calling a Meteor Method inside a Promise Callback [Halting w/o Error]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377304/calling-a-meteor-method-inside-a-promise-callback-halting-w-o-error)

Comment: you should probably be returning the promise to make it work. eg. `return gumroad.listSales(after, before, page).then(doThisAfterResponse);` in both places. But that entirely depends on how meteor methods being handed. *note: I'm not a meteor guy*

Answer (score 1):

I ended up ditching the NPM package and writing my own API call. I could never figure out how to make my call inside the `.then()`. Here's the code:

```js
fetchGumroadData: () => {
  let sales = [];

  const fetchData = (page = 1) => {
    let options = {
      data: {
        access_token: Meteor.settings.gumroadAccessKey,
        before: '2099-12-04',
        after: '2014-12-04',
        page: page,
      }
    };
    HTTP.call('GET', 'https://api.gumroad.com/v2/sales', options, (err,res) => {
      if (err) {  // API call failed
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
      } else {    // API call successful
        sales.push(...res.data.sales);
        res.data.next_page_url ? fetchData(page + 1) : Meteor.call('addSalesFromAPI', sales);
      }
    });
  };

  fetchData();  // run the function to fetch data recursively
}
```